# Correlations in the Hellings-Downs curve for the NANOGrav 15-year dataset

Tags: gravitational-waves, correlation-functions, data-analysis, pulsars

I'm trying to reproduce the Figure 1c from the paper ["The NANOGrav 15-year Data Set: Evidence for a Gravitational-Wave Background"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.16213.pdf). This graph corresponds to pulsar pair correlations of the timing residuals as function of the pulsars' angular separation. However I don't quite understand how to find these correlations.

I already downloaded the data set and I'm using the PINT library in python. If I'm not wrong, the timing residuals are easily accessed with:

```
model, history = get_model_and_toas(par_file, tim_file) 
res = Residuals(history, model).time_resids.to(u.us)
t = history.get_mjds() # Modified julian days
```

but when I plot them I get something like this:

[image]

(In the picture the two pulsars are J0023+0923 and J1811-2405)

My question is, how can I find the correlations, given the fact that the domains are not equal, the data sets have different sizes and even when the domains seem to coincide, the specific x-values don't. Because of this I can't just find a Pearson correlation coefficient for example. So, is there a special correlation I could use? or is there a transformation I could apply to the data sets so they become easily analyzable? And is there a specific function for this inside PINT?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? @Just_A_Pangolin